# Why weights are not squared in the weighted Euclidean distance formula?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I am working on Data Mining and need distance between data points.

With two points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$ & weights $w_1$ and $w_2$ respectively. The euclidean distance is: 
$$
\sqrt{w_1\times(x_2-x_1)^2+w_2\times(y_2-y_1)^2}.
$$
I think intuitively $w_1$ & $w_2$ were supposed to be squared as they are getting square rooted in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. 
$w$ is just a name for $\frac{1}{s^2}$, where $s$ for standard deviation. 
Full answer here:

http://www.econ.upf.edu/~michael/stanford/maeb4.pdf

Comment: +1 for the reference. But I think the answer to the OP's question is "no". The entire expression is a square root. The weights should not be squared (they _are_ squares).

Comment: @Ethan Bolker, I see your point. I found it correct because $w=(\frac{1}{s})^2$

Comment: @mitsos what if I take my own arbitrary weights?

Comment: @mrityunjoynath you choose $w$ as the inverse variance of each variable. Why did you use this formula in the first place? I think the pdf link was pretty clear in page 4-7.

Comment: @mitsos yeah now it's clear. Awesome explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @mrityunjoynath good question, helped me clear it also.